# Is it possible to add pgvector extension on top of postgres:15.3-alpine images

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, pgvector

I'm trying to dockerize pg-vector and I found this Dockerfile from the official repository.
https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/blob/master/Dockerfile#L2C1-L3C1

The Dockerfile currently uses postgres base image right now, I'm wondering if I can add the pgvector extension on top of the alpine images. If not, what are other possible options?

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: There is already a docker image: https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#installation-notes

Answer (score 4):

This extension of the Alpine docker image worked for me:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM postgres:14.4-alpine AS pgvector-builder
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add clang
RUN apk add llvm13-dev
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone --branch v0.4.4 https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector.git
WORKDIR /home/pgvector
RUN make
RUN make install

FROM postgres:14.4-alpine
COPY --from=pgvector-builder /usr/local/lib/postgresql/bitcode/vector.index.bc /usr/local/lib/postgresql/bitcode/vector.index.bc
COPY --from=pgvector-builder /usr/local/lib/postgresql/vector.so /usr/local/lib/postgresql/vector.so
COPY --from=pgvector-builder /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension

$ docker build -t postgres:14.4-alpine-pgvector .
```

Comment: Thank you for this, just worked for me without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Updated instructions are below for newer alpine images based on deed02392's answer

```
ARG PGGDOCKERTAG=13-alpine3.17
FROM postgres:$PGGDOCKERTAG AS pgvector-builder
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add clang
RUN apk add llvm15-dev llvm15
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone --branch v0.4.4 https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector.git
WORKDIR /home/pgvector
RUN make
RUN make install

FROM postgres:$PGGDOCKERTAG
COPY --from=pgvector-builder /usr/local/lib/postgresql/bitcode/vector.index.bc /usr/local/lib/postgresql/bitcode/vector.index.bc
COPY --from=pgvector-builder /usr/local/lib/postgresql/vector.so /usr/local/lib/postgresql/vector.so
COPY --from=pgvector-builder /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension
```

Comment: This worked for me. 
Also needed to add `RUN apk add clang15`